# How do I edit/send a pdf template in an email?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, email, pdf

I have a template that I would like to make edits and send via email.  I have the following code, but the edited pdf says my data is "damaged and cannot be repaired". I am not sure I am pulling the edited pdf to be sent. Any help is appreciated.

```
   using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())  
    {    
        PdfStamper formFiller = new PdfStamper(reader, ms);
        AcroFields formFields = formFiller.AcroFields;
        formFields.SetField("Name", formData.Name);
        formFields.SetField("Location", formData.Address);
        formFields.SetField("Date", DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());
        formFields.SetField("Email", formData.Email);
        formFiller.FormFlattening = true;
        formFiller.Close();

        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("to@email.com"));
        msg.From = new MailAddress("from@email.com");
        msg.Subject = "Application Form";
        msg.Body = "TEST";
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        ms.Position = 0;
        msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms, "Application.pdf", "application/x-pdf"));
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("10.1.1.15");
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    }
```

Comment: If you take out the e-mail logic and just edit and save the PDF, is it still corrupt?

Comment: I think that is what I would like to do... but I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I think when you finish writting data into a MemoryStream you need to reset the position of the stream to 0 before reading from it again.</strike>

Try using a FileStream instead of MemoryStream to save into a temporary file so you can narrow down the issue.

Comment: I had the ms.Position = 0; Nice catch, but unfortunately that wasnt it :(